# Adding logo to a cat image in Python

Tags: python, image-processing

For the captioned, here's the code (courtesy Automate the Boring Stuff) and I'd tweaked it a bit.

```
import os
from PIL import Image

SQUARE_FIT_SIZE = 300
LOGO_FILENAME = 'catlogo.png'

logoIm = Image.open(LOGO_FILENAME)
logoWidth, logoHeight = logoIm.size

# Loop over all files in the working directory.
for filename in os.listdir('.'):
    if not (filename.endswith('.png') or filename.endswith('.jpg')) \
       or filename == LOGO_FILENAME:
        continue # skip non-image files and the logo file itself

    im = Image.open(filename)
    width, height = im.size

    # Add logo.
    print('Adding logo to %s...' % (filename))
    im.paste(logoIm, (width - logoWidth, height - logoHeight), logoIm)

    # Save changes.
    im.save('Cat with Logo.png')
```

[image: Cat Logo]

[image: Cat Image]

For some reason, the logo failed to be added at the end. Is something wrong with the `save` command?

Comment: Are you sure that `if width > SQUARE_FIT_SIZE and height > SQUARE_FIT_SIZE:` statement is getting executed properly?

Try to give  `print` statement in the very first line after the check to see if it's getting executed properly.

Comment: @Koustav: As you rightly said, it was a rookie mistake not to have checked it. For this question, the problem lies at the very end, I think. I'm cleaning the code to focus on it. Let me know what you think.

Comment: Your source image is of much smaller dimension that your logo image. Please go through the docs carefully and make necessary modifications in your code. https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.paste

Also if you notice carefully, it's not that it isn't getting pasted at all, the front paw could be seen in your second image. You need to make adjustments to the image dimensions in order to make it fit perfectly.

Comment: Your top left pixel coordinate `(width - logoWidth, height - logoHeight)` is `(-583, -468)`. Hence you only get to see the front leg of the logo cat.

Answer (score 2):

I realized `resizeAndAddLogo.py` resizes the file to which the logo is pasted on, not the logo size proportioned to the file. We don't want that. So I changed the script to change logo size with the ratio of 1/5 to the image file.

```
...
# Resize the logo.
print(f'Resizing logo to fit {filename}...')
sLogo = logoIm.resize((int(width / 5), int(height / 5)))
sLogoWidth, sLogoHeight = sLogo.size

# Add the logo.
print(f'Adding logo to {filename}...')
im.paste(sLogo, (width - sLogoWidth, height - sLogoHeight), sLogo)
...
```

At this point, I don't need `SQUARE_FIT_SIZE = 300`, so I deleted it and made the code shorter. Here's my full script.

```
import os
from PIL import Image

LOGO_FILENAME = 'catlogo.png'
logoIm = Image.open(LOGO_FILENAME)
os.makedirs('withLogo', exist_ok=True)

# Loop over all files in the working directory.
for filename in os.listdir():
    if not (filename.endswith('.png') or filename.endswith('.jpg')) or filename == LOGO_FILENAME:
        continue

    im = Image.open(filename)
    width, height = im.size

    # Resize the logo.
    print(f'Resizing logo to fit {filename}...')
    sLogo = logoIm.resize((int(width / 5), int(height / 5)))
    sLogoWidth, sLogoHeight = sLogo.size

    # Add the logo.
    print(f'Adding logo to {filename}...')
    im.paste(sLogo, (width - sLogoWidth, height - sLogoHeight), sLogo)

    # Save changes.
    im.save(os.path.join('withLogo', filename))
```

Note that resized logo should be assigned to be used in loop.

And this one of the resulted images.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@harryghgim You idea is great but I think that the point of this project was to unify all pictures to one size with the logo so combining Your solution I've resized logo added to pictures and than resided all using SQUARE_FIT_SIZE = 300

```
import os
from PIL import Image

SQUARE_FIT_SIZE = 300
LOGO_FILENAME = 'catlogo.png'
logoIm = Image.open(LOGO_FILENAME)
logoWidth, logoHeight = logoIm.size

os.makedirs('withLogo', exist_ok=True)
#TODO: loop over all files
for filename in os.listdir('.'):
    if not (filename.endswith('.png') or filename.endswith('.jpg')) or filename == 
    LOGO_FILENAME:
        continue
    im = Image.open(filename)
    width, height = im.size
#TODO: Resize the logo.
    print(f'Resizing logo to fit {filename}...')
    sLogo = logoIm.resize((int(width / 5), int(height / 5)))
    sLogoWidth, sLogoHeight = sLogo.size

#TODO: Add logo
    print('Dodanie logo do obrazu %s...' % (filename))
    im.paste(sLogo, (width - sLogoWidth, height - sLogoHeight), sLogo)
# TODO: check if there is a need to resize picture
    if width > SQUARE_FIT_SIZE and height > SQUARE_FIT_SIZE:
# TODO: count new width and height
        if width > height:
            height = int((SQUARE_FIT_SIZE / width) * height)
            width = SQUARE_FIT_SIZE
        else:
            width = int((SQUARE_FIT_SIZE / height) * width)
            height = SQUARE_FIT_SIZE
# TODO: change image size
        print('Zmiana wielkości obrazu %s...' % (filename))
        im = im.resize((width, height))
#TODO: save images
        im.save(os.path.join('withLogo', filename))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the Author forgot to add that part intentionally but I came up with a quick fix. Just add `SQUARE_FIT_SIZE_LOGO` variable for logo as well based on the ratio. In my example it's one 10th of the `SQUARE_FIT_SIZE`. Then, just apply the if clause in similar way used for the `width` and `height`. use `logoIm.resize` before saving the file.

```
#! python3
# resizeAndAddLogopy - Resized all images in current working directory to fit
# in a 300x300 square, and adds catlogo.png to the lower-right corner.
import os
from PIL import Image
SQUARE_FIT_SIZE = 300
# size of logo to be pasted based on ratio
SQUARE_FIT_SIZE_OF_LOGO = int(SQUARE_FIT_SIZE / 10)
LOGO_FILENAME = 'catlogo.png'
logoIm = Image.open(LOGO_FILENAME)
logoWidth, logoHeight = logoIm.size
# Loop over all files in the working directory.
for filename in os.listdir('.'):
    if not (filename.lower().endswith('.png') or filename.lower().endswith('.jpg')) \
            or filename == LOGO_FILENAME:
        continue # skip non-image files and the logo itself
    im = Image.open(filename)
    width, height = im.size
    # Check if image needs to be resized.
    if width > SQUARE_FIT_SIZE and height > SQUARE_FIT_SIZE:
        # Calculate the new width and height to resize to.
        if width > height:
            height = int((SQUARE_FIT_SIZE / width) * height)
            width = SQUARE_FIT_SIZE
        else:
            width = int((SQUARE_FIT_SIZE / height) * width)
            height = SQUARE_FIT_SIZE
    # Check if logo needs to be resized.
    if logoWidth > SQUARE_FIT_SIZE_OF_LOGO and logoHeight > SQUARE_FIT_SIZE_OF_LOGO:
        # Calculate th new width and height to resize to.
        if logoWidth > logoHeight:
            logoHeight = int((SQUARE_FIT_SIZE_OF_LOGO / logoWidth) * logoHeight)
            logoWidth = SQUARE_FIT_SIZE_OF_LOGO
        else:
            logoWidth = int((SQUARE_FIT_SIZE_OF_LOGO / logoHeight) * logoWidth)
            logoHeight = SQUARE_FIT_SIZE_OF_LOGO
    # Resize the image.
    print('Resizing %s...' % (filename))
    im = im.resize((width, height))
    # Resize the logo.
    print('Resizing %s...' % (LOGO_FILENAME))
    logoIm = logoIm.resize((logoWidth, logoHeight))
    # Add the logo.
    print('Adding logo to %s...' % (filename))
    im.paste(logoIm, (width - logoWidth, height - logoHeight), logoIm)
    # Save changes.
    im.save(os.path.join('withLogo', filename))
```